# Get the value of multiple input texts with Actionscript 3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, loops, input

I'm trying to create a ActionScript application to calculate the volume of sand a mining company can extract off a river. So I got in the stage like 4 input texts named as "WidthOne", "WidthTwo", "WidthThree" and "WidthFour" and other 4 inputs, "HeightOne" ... "Height Four". The mathmatics goes like "WidthOne × HeightOne" ... "WidthFour × HeightFour" and the results go to dynamic fields named "ResultOne" ... "ResultFour".

Is there any way to use a loop to get the value of these fields so I don't need to do it all manually as I need to create other input texts in the stage? I got a working one in HTML and Javascript and basically it is like:

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i ++) {
    var WidthInputID = ['WidthOne','WidthTwo','WidthThree','WidthFour'];
    var HeightInputID = ['HeightOne','HeightTwo','HeightThree','HeightFour'];
    var ResultsInputID = ['ResultOne','ResultTwo','ResultThree','ResultFour'];

    var Width = document.getElementById(WidthInputID[i]).value;
    var Height = document.getElementById(HeightInputID[i]).value;
    var Result = document.getElementById(ResultsInputID[i]).value = Width*Height;
}
```

I don't know if I made myself clear because my English is bad, so I'm sorry if I'm not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var widthInputID:Array = ['WidthOne','WidthTwo','WidthThree','WidthFour'];
var heightInputID:Array = ['HeightOne','HeightTwo','HeightThree','HeightFour'];
var resultsInputID:Array = ['ResultOne','ResultTwo','ResultThree','ResultFour'];

for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

    var width:Number = Number(this[widthInputID[i]].text);
    var height:Number = Number(this[heightInputID[i]].text);
    var result:Number = width*height;
    this[resultsInputID[i]].text = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the same strategy in AS3. The main differences would be:

1. To access an element on the stage, instead of *document.getElementById("elementId")* you would use:

   ```
   this["instanceName"]
   ```
2. The property name for the content of the text field isn't *value*. The property is called *text*.